# Symfony: joining two forms in the same page

Tags: forms, symfony1

i'm trying to join in the same action the login and the register forms. This is what i'm trying:

modules/miembros/actions.class.php

```
  public function executeAux(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
        // I execute this action

  }
```

modules/miembros/templates/auxSuccess.php

```
<?php include_component('sfGuardRegister', 'register'); ?>
<?php include_component('sfGuardAuth', 'signin'); ?>
```

modules/miembros/components.class.php

```
public function executeSignin($request)
{

  if ( $request->isMethod( 'post' ) && ($request-
>getParameter('submit')=='signin') ){

    $this->form->bind( $request->getParameter( 'login' ) );
    if ( $this->form->isValid() ){
      $this->getController()->getActionStack()->getLastEntry()->getActionInstance()->redirect( '@home' );
    }
  }

}
```

modules/miembros/templates/_signin.php

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('miembros/aux?submit=signin') ?>"
method="post">

        <?php echo $form['email_address']->renderLabel() ?>
        <?php echo $form['email_address'] ?>
...
```

It's working ok, but i would to know if you have other alternatives.

For example i don't like the line:
    $this->getController()->getActionStack()->getLastEntry()->getActionInstance()->redirect( '@home' );

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't process the form in your component , you should do it in your action. the components meant to be reusable views that can get included in other templates (similar to partials, but with some code behind them to sustain more complex data retrieves). If you want to show the form in a component so you can reuse it, you can, but you should handle the form in another action.

Comment: I have a new proposal based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to the comment of matei this is my new proposal. What's your opinion now?

modules/miembros/actions/actions.class.php

```
public function executeAux(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    return $this->renderPartial('aux');
}
```

modules/miembros/templates/_aux.php

```
if(!isset($form_register)){

    $form_register = new sfGuardFormRegisterByOthers();
} 

include_partial('sfGuardRegister/register', array('form' => $form_register));


if(!isset($form_signin)){

    $form_signin = new sfGuardFormSigninByEmail();
}

include_partial('sfGuardAuth/signin', array('form' => $form_signin));
```

modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/_signin

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('sfGuardAuth/signin') ?>" method="post">
```

modules/miembros/sfGuardAuth/actions.class.php

```
 if ($this->form->isValid())
 {
   //...

 }else{

    return $this->renderPartial('miembros/aux', array('form_signin' => $this->form));

 }
```

It works also.

Javi

Comment: it been a long time since this post but ireal have a question casue im working on a project with symfony 1.4 ?
Could you explain to me how by rendering a partial does not include a template ?